# Rendering an image in a new perspective from 2 or more viewpoints

Tags: computer-vision

I have a screen that I want to act like a mirror, however I cannot mount a camera behind the screen to get the right perspective. I can mount cameras around the screen and know their position in an X/Y/Z space and their focal length. Is there anyway to take the output of those cameras and render a new image with the perspective that I require? One that would allow the screen to emulate a mirror.

Comment: you could do a full 3d reconstruction of the scene in front of the display, using those cameras. then you can synthesize arbitrary views, as they would be required to emulate the picture in a mirror, as viewed by a human/camera in front of the screen/mirror. you should just use a kinect or similar "RGBD sensor". don't bother implementing your own stereo rig. that's fiddly.

Comment: Is there prior art for doing it this way?

Comment: surely. I believe you're well equipped to do the research. there are probably also AI methods for novel view synthesis but that's beyond me.